# Fat controllers : How do i make it slim?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, service-layer

I am developing a blog engine using EF 6 and MVC 5.

I have decided not to use Repository pattern or UoW as it is already implemented in EF 6 at framework level.

The solution contains following layers.

**DataModels layer:** It has simple POCO's which are auto generated & a dbContext.

```
public partial class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string PostBody { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
```

**Service Layer:**

```
public interface IBlogEngine
    {
        List<Article> GetFrontPageBlogPosts();
        void SaveArticle(Article article);
        List<Article> GetArticlesByStatus(string isPublished);
        Article GetBySlug(string slug);
        Article GetById(int id);
        bool Exists(string slugUrl);
        void Delete(int id);
    }
```

`IBlogEngine`  implementation. Some methods implementation are omitted for brevity.

```
public class BlogEngine : IBlogEngine
    {
        private readonly dbContext _context;

        public BlogEngine(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public void SaveArticle(Article article)
        {
            if (article.Id == 0)
            {
                _context.Articles.Add(article);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }



        public Article GetBySlug(string slug)
        {
            return _context.Articles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Slug == slug.Trim());
        }


    }
```

**UI Layer**

```
 public class ArticleController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBlogEngine _engine;
        public ArticleController(IBlogEngine engine)
        {
            _engine = engine;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(string slug)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slug))
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var article = _engine.GetBySlug(slug);

            if (article == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var model = new EditViewModel { Id = article.Id, Slug = article.Slug, 
            Title = article.Title, PostBody = article.PostBody, IsPublished = true };

            return View("Create", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel blogPost)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Create", blogPost);
            }
            // Get Article by Id
            var article = _engine.GetById(blogPost.Id);

            if (article == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            // Update it
            article.Id = blogPost.Id;
            article.Title = blogPost.Title.Trim();
            article.Slug = blogPost.Slug.ToUrlSlug();
            article.PostBody = blogPost.PostBody;
            article.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            article.IsPublished = blogPost.IsPublished;
            article.Author = User.Identity.Name;

            // Save it
            _engine.SaveArticle(article);

            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Article");
        }

    }
```

**The Problem**
Consider a scenario where a user is finished editing his old blog post/article and hits submit button to update he blog post/article.

Is my HTTP POST Edit action too fat ? I feel that the controller is doing too may things here.

1. Get the existing article from DB
2. Update it with ViewModel values
3. Call `SaveArticle` method from service layer.

How can i put this controller on diet ?

Shouldn't the Service Layer method  `SaveArticle` do the job of retrieving an article from Db and update it with new values and call SaveChanges method ?

If above statement is true, How can i pass the ViewModel to ServiceLayer method ? Isn't it a bad decision to allow ViewModels leak into Service layer ?

How do i handle this ? I am confused and need some help.

Comment: You should in theory be using a dedicated model to post back to your controller, rather than posting back the whole ViewModel. With a dedicated model, it is indeed correct to give that model to your repository/service layer to perform its actions.

Comment: I am posting entire ViewModel to controller action (HTTP POST) because it is required as i dont know what fields are changed by user. 
Do you mean i should have Article instead of EditViewModel  in HTTP POST action method ?

Comment: Looks good to me, and is doing exactly what a controller POST method should. Accept a view model, validate it, map to the domain model, save it and redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Is it ok for a ServiceLayaer method to return a DTO instead of Domain object ? Because, in some methods i return entire domain object but at Controller level, i need only few properties.

Comment: Don't see any problem with that if your using view models to display/edit only the data you need

Comment: This controller doesn't look so fat. Maybe it's just the jeans it has on?

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, it gets confusing to me as well sometimes as to what and how much the controller should be doing to serve a request.

In most of my implementation I do following:

1. Accept the viewModel input object in Post method (the input values are validated at client side).
2. Check the ModelState.
3. Convert the viewmodel object into domain model object. I use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.codeplex.com/).
4. Give it to service method. It does what needs to be done for the operation.
5. Return appropriate result based on operation.

I were you, I would write:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel blogPost)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Create", blogPost);
        }

        // Use AutoMapper for ViewModel to DomainModel conversion
        var blogPostDomainModel = Mapper.Map<EditViewModel, BlogPost>(blogPost);

        // Save it - Update the object in persistent store. It may throw
        // exception if something wrong while updating the object. Having
        // validated input from UI that should only happen due to server
        // error.
        _engine.SaveArticle(blogPostDomainModel);

        return RedirectToAction("List", "Article");
    }
```

Comment: So if i don't use auto-mapper, what i am doing is similar to the code you posted.

I just need to create new instance of Domain Object and map its properties from ViewModel & finally pass it to a service layer method. 

Another question. Is it OK to reference domain model (BlogPost) in to the controller ? What if my domain model changes, wont it break the controllers ?

Comment: Yes you are right. AutoMapper save us from doing this plumbing job. Well I consider it ok as I store all the domain models/entities in separate assembly. I got another assembly where I keep everything EF specific. Web assembly does not have reference to EF. I agree changes into model will break the controller. But it will in any case. Isn't it?